# Using Terminal In 12.04

Tags: command-line

When I try to use terminal, I put in a command and then it asks for my password.  I type my password and nothing comes up on the screen.  Help?

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons, commands, like `sudo`, that request a user's password set the terminal to "NO ECHO" so people surfing your shoulder cannot grab your password. The password you type goes to the computer, but the computer doesn't send the characters back to the terminal.